# Python Writing LSystem Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a function which is "processString(axiom, rules)"

**that processes the entire string axiom, and returns the new string**

Also, I want to create a function "createLSystem(iterations, axiom, rules)"

**that runs the transformations on the axiom for a number of iterations as specified by iterations**

And this is what I wrote so far

```
def applyRules(char, rules):
    for rule_list in (rule.split(':') for rule in rules):
        char = char.replace(rule_list[0], rule_list[1])
    return char

def processString(axoism, rules):
    newstr = ""
    for ch in rules:
        newstr = newstr + applyRules(ch)
    return newstr

def createLSystem(iterations, axiom, rules):
    startString = axiom
    endString = ""
    for i in range(iterations):
        endString = processString(startString)
        startString = endString
    return endString
```

axoism, rules and iterations have to be asked to users.
But I am not sure if the codes are written right, because it is not working as it should I think.

Comment: What is `applyRules`?

Comment: I just added! Thank you for comment

Comment: It looks like you could use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) here

Comment: I am not supposed to use that function..